# How to clear the shared preference when app removed from taskmanager?

Tags: android

I am using `shared preference` for **storing username and password**.
I want `shared preference` value to be **cleared** only when the app being removed from **task manager**.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by overriding `onDestroy()` in one of your activities (see [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()))

something like:

```
@Override
void onDestroy() {
    clearSharedPrefs();  // implement your function here
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

It's not guaranteed that onDestroy will be called, so perhaps this is not the best way to go.

It might be better to store the username and password in a static variable (Which gets cleared on app exit), perhaps in a Singleton fashion.

Comment: I dont want sharedprefrence data to be ceared on proper app exit,I want shared prefrence value to be cleared only when the app being removed from task manager.

Comment: There is no way for the app to detect why it is being shutdown. You can't single out the task manager.